Test with multiple define values within the same test
We are using ceedling to unit test a driver. Unfortunately the driver has to support multiple hardware versions, so some functions had to be duplicated, similar to this:
#ifdef HW_VERSION_1
bool myfunction(int param1)
{
  TEST_PARAM_RANGE(param1, 0, 5);
  ...
  fct1();
  ...
}
#else
bool myfunction(int param1)
{
  TEST_PARAM_RANGE(param1, 5, 10);
  ...
  fct2();
  ...
}
#endif

Depending on the defined flag we have different input ranges and different function calls.
The unit tests look this way:
#ifdef HW_VERSION_1
  check_if_param_invalid((int[]){-1, 6});
  ...
  fct1_Expect();
  myfunction(3);
#else
  check_if_param_invalid((int[]){4, 11});
  ...
  fct2_Expect();
  myfunction(6);
#endif

For unit testing we have 2 ceedling projects, for HW_VERSION_1 and HW_VERSION_2. The flags are defined in the 2 .yml files under :defines: :common:
This means we have to run the unit tests 2x, and get 2 coverage results, which we monitor.
Is it possible to test these 2 versions of myfunction in a single unit test? Or at least get a single coverage from the 2? My goal is to get a single coverage result on the whole codebase, independent of the HW_VERSION, to get an overall impression of the test quality.

What exactly do you have in mind by "a single coverage result on the whole codebase"? Is that different from (coverage(HW_VERSION_1) + coverage(HW_VERSION_2)) / 2, or possibly a weighted version of that?

coverage of all the lines of code, which are there (not a sum and not a weighted version) - what i would get if there was no #ifdef, but myfunction_HW_VERSION1() and myfunction_HW_VERSION2()

For your project, would you consider an answer focused on the build system rather than the testing framework? For example, you could create one header file with the Interface functions your driver code supports. Then you can write multiple .c files with the implementations targeted for each hardware version. You can then compile multiple library targets with whatever build system you are using. Same goes for the tests. Include your interface, test those functions once, but compile multiple test targets linked against the different implementation libraries that support each hardware version.
